# Elasticsearch: aggregation accuracy

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

If I am running an aggregation against a query - will the results be accurate? Is the doc_count inaccurate only when there is no query?
[aggregation accuracy](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_document_counts_are_approximate)

Answer (score 1):

To get accurate aggregation document count, you can explicitly set the size parameter to 0. See [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size) for more information. But mind you, this is more expensive.

Comment: so, by default, if I have an aggregation ran against a query and specify the size, then I can get results that are not accurate?

Comment: Yes. This is very nicely explained at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_document_counts_are_approximate.

Comment: that is the same link I gave in my question - but there is the plain aggregation. would it be the same behavior if the aggregation is 'activated' in the context of a query?

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregation activated in the context of a query"? Can you explain with a simple example please?

Comment: {query: {some query}, aggs{}}